# Prevent SQL injection via "quotename" with stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, exec, sql-injection

I am trying to make some code "sql-injection-proof". I have been advised to use `QUOTENAME`.

This works:

```
select 'abc[]def'
```

and it gives similar results to

```
select QUOTENAME('abc[]def')
```

However while the following works:

```
exec sp_spaceused 'STMALOGqueue'
```

This does not:

```
exec sp_spaceused QUOTENAME('STMALOGqueue')
```

I get an annoying error:

```
Incorrect syntax near 'STMALOGqueue'
```

The actual code that I am trying to proof from injection is hardcoded in some C#. For reference:

```
string sp_spaceused = @"
drop table if exists #temp
create table #temp(name nvarchar(100), rows int, reserved nvarchar(100), data nvarchar(100), index_size nvarchar(100), unused nvarchar(100))

insert into #temp
exec sp_spaceused QUOTENAME('{0}')";
```

I am using `String.format` to insert the relevant table name into this string and then execute it. Currently it does not work

Comment: Please note that if you can change the c# code to use a parameter instead of string concatenation, that would be the best protection against SQL Injection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store `QUOTENAME('STMALOGqueue')` result into a variable and use it for stored procedure parameter:

```
declare @test as varchar(100)

set @test = QUOTENAME('STMALOGqueue')

exec sp_spaceused @test
```

it works.